# Source patching audio "light" will not turn on

Tags: premiere

The basic question is why the audio source patch of the first audio track will not toggle on.

I'm looking for confirmation or the correct reason.

I created a sequence preset based upon the DLSR 1080p preset and change it to be square 1080 x 1080 but did not change any of the audio settings.  I created a sequence with that preset.  The preset has three audio tracks.

I put my source sequence and set in and out points and then hit over write and it put the audio in a new (fourth) track.  So I undid it and then tried to toggle the source patch "light" of the A1 track but it will not toggle on.

After reading and surfing, I came to the belief that this is because my source audio is different.  The properties of the source says 48000 HZ - Multichannel while the target sequence properties says 48000 HZ - Stereo.

It also seems I can not change these settings once the sequence is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. If you have an audio asset active into the Source Panel, you can't activate the Source Patching for an audio track that does not match the type of the asset. Premiere seperates between *Standard (Stereo)*, *Mono*, *5.1* and *Adaptive*. You can tell the track type by the corresponding icons in the timeline:

[image: Audio Track Types]

From Top to Bottom: Standard (no Icon), 5.1, Adaptive, Mono.

You can't put Multichannel audio (where *multi* means more than two) in Stereo tracks and vice versa. Instead, you need to create new tracks of the matching type. To do this, right-click on any audio track<sup>1</sup> and select *Add Tracks…* from the context-menu. This opens a pop-up menu where you can chose to add any number of Audio and Video Tracks. Make sure to select the right Track Type (in your case, you'll need 5.1 or Adaptive). You can also delete the superfluous Audio Tracks from the same context menu (accessed via right-click).

Note that this will not change the Audio Master Type. When creating a sequence, you can change this in the *Tracks* tab, as well as control how many audio tracks of which types are added.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that you have to right-click in the right area, as there are several available context-menues hidden in the timeline, depending on where you click. To access the context-menu described above, you need to click anywhere between the Sync Lock icon (to the right of the Track Targeting toggle) and the column containing the Track Type icons (to the left of the timeline itself). You can also access this via the menu over *Sequence* → *Add Tracks…*.